# Input read in MPI slave processor

Tags: mpi

Here is my pseudo-code. Say I have 1 master processor and 4 slave processors:

```
if (id==0)
{
  MPI_Send to x1, x2 to processor 1;
              x3, x4 to processor 2;
              x5, x6 to processor 3;
              x7, x8 to processor 4;
  MPI_Receive y1, y2, ..........., y8 ;
}
if (id != 0)
{
  MPI_Recv x values (each processor receives 2 x values);
  in the input file, modify the certain rows into value of the two x values;
  My function: read the input files and compute two y values;
  MPI send y values to master processor ;
}
```

The problem is, every processor would read one single input file at the same time which could cause error. How do I solve this problem ? Thanks in advance!

**Update**:

What I want to achieve is,
every MPI processor will execute my function (in pseudo code) to compute `y` values. In a different processor, the function uses different `x` values. So I wrote some codes to modify the input file to the `x` values (`x` values are different in different processors) before the input reading of the function.

So this causes a problem, every processor is trying to modify a single file at the same time and every processor is executing the function to read the modified input file. This of course resulted in errors.

I need your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use send/recv. Use MPI_Scatter and MPI_Gather

Comment: If I use scatter and gather, there won't be a error with the input reading ? I do not think so.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't understand the question/issue you face... Your pseudo-code is far from clear enough for me to grasp the problem

Comment: So you have a file which is modified by some processes and read by other processes at the same time? Why would you do that? The question is, what do you really want to achieve?

Comment: Could [MPI_IO](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.0/mpi-20-html/mpi2-report.htm#Node0) solve your problem ? There are routines like [`MPI_File_read_at()`](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.0/mpi-20-html/node191.htm#Node191) or `MPI_File_write_at()` that could be helpful.

Comment: @haraldkl  in the code, the funtion which computes two y values has to read an input file. This input file would be modified before the reading by the x value (each processor has different x values). So I want to achieve to apply the the function to compute y values in each processors (because the function computation takes long time, I want it to be paralleled). The problem is this function has to read input file. Thanks!

Comment: @francis, thank you very much. I will check these routines!

Comment: @haraldkl, actually, I have a file which is modified by some processes and read by the corresponding process. That means process 1 modify the input and then read by process 1, process 2 modify the input and then read by process 2.

Comment: @Gilles I have updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: I think that @francis is right, what you need is `MPI_File_write_at{_all}()` and `MPI_File_read_at{_all}()` plus some `MPI_File_sync()` and possibly `MPI_Barrier()` to make sure that updates are propagated to all processes. But ultimately, the question is "do you really need to use a file?", Couldn't you do that by simply use in-memory storage, possibly with one-sided communications? If you can store the data in memory, that'd be much faster and safer.

Comment: Using files to communicate between processes in the same MPI program seems just plain wrong.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark 100% agreed. The **only** reason I can think of for justifying using a file like this is if the file pre-exists and needs to be kept up-to-date after the job finishes **and** its size exceeds by a great deal the cumulated memory size available for the MPI job. Otherwise, there ought to be a (much much) better solution, such as the one based on one-sided which I mentioned already.

Comment: "I need your help!": It is not obvious from your question what you actually want to achieve. What is the algorithm you want to implement, and what is the purpose of that weird file?

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for your reply. The function I use need a a lot of input. So I need an input file. Each processor just modifies a part of the input in the input file. Is it possible that the input file is read by each processor, then saved and modified in the buffer of each processor, then read by the function ?

Comment: As far as I (try to) understand your request, I suppose it is possible. But if you want any sort of effective help for doing that, you'll need to elaborate on your request and post some **actual** code here.